# Related Rates, two ships

Tags: analytic-geometry, physics

> There are two ships, A and B.
>   Ship B is 32 miles south of Ship A.
>   Ship A is travelling south at 16 mph. Ship B is travelling east at 12 mph. 
>   After how long do the ships cease to approach one another and how far apart are they when this happens?

Basically, I drew a diagram putting Ship B southwest of Ship A. I found how long it would take Ship A to cross the 32 miles (2 hours). Then I found how long Ship B would have travelled in that time (24 miles).
Next, I designated point C as the point where they stop approaching one another (the vertex of the triangle with the right angle). I designated variable x to AC, y to BC, and z to AB. Then I solved for Z using the pythagorean theorem. Then I differentiated all the variables with respect to time. I substituted 32 miles for the x value, and the speeds 16 mph and 12 mph respectively for dx/dt and dy/dt. Finally, I recognized that when they "cease to approach one another", the length z, which was previously decreasing, goes to zero (and then begins to increase). Thus I substituted in zero for dz/dt. Finally I solved for y. I get approximately 42.67 miles. This is how far ship B started from point C! Since I already found that it travels 24 miles within the 2 hour timeframe, the final answer I gave for the distance between the ships when they cease to approach each other was 18.67 miles.

---

I just need to know if this is right LOL. If not, what is wrong with my approach?

My approach was in fact wrong simply due to the way I set up the question. B is DIRECTLY SOUTH of A! When it says 'cease to approach' all that means is that the distance between the ships is at a minimum! There's a discussion in the comments if you want to check it out. Thanks guys :)

Comment: I am not able to follow. Where is point C? Is it related to ship A or ship B? Draw a figure. Anyway I think you complicate it too much

Comment: I can't add pictures because I don't have 10 reputation

Comment: I am getting $17.8$ miles after about hour and a half

Comment: How did you get that answer?

Answer (score 3):

Ship A is only moving along $y$ axis. The position is given by $x_A=0$ and $$y_A=32-16t$$
Ship B is only moving along $x$ axis. The position is given by $y_B=0$ and $$x_B=12t$$
The distance squared is $$d^2(t)=(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2=(12t)^2+(32-16t)^2$$
The ship stop approaching when the absolute value of the distance (or distance square) have a minimum.
Just set the derivative to zero: $$\frac{d}{dt}d^2(t)=0$$
Now calculate $t$. Take this value, and plug it back into the equation for the distance.

Comment: I don't really understand the notation at the end, I'm a beginner sorry. But I would really appreciate it if you could tell me why my approach is wrong?

Comment: I see that @gt6989b gave you an answer already. The notation is the derivative with respect to time of the distance, otherwise known as velocity. When the two ships approach, then go separate ways, the velocity changes sign. So at the minimum distance it is 0. The non-calculus way is to find the vertex of the parabola for $d^2(t)$. And I see that you already figured out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Here is perhaps a simpler approach. Put $B$ initially at the origin, traveling along the positive $x$-axis at $12$ mph, and $A$ at $(0,32)$ initially, travelling at $-16$ mph.

Then, at any time $t \in [0,2]$, you have $A(t) = (0, 32-16t)$ and $B(t) = (12t,0)$, so the square of the distance between them is given by
$$
d(t) = (32-16t)^2 + (12t)^2.
$$
It's clear $d(0) = 32^2$ and $d(2) = 24^2$. Can you find where does $d$ attain its minimum?

---

**UPDATE**

After you posted your answer, I will complete this to show the solution without Calculus techniques. We have
$$
d(t) = (12^2+ 16^2) t^2 - 2 \cdot 32 \cdot 16 t + 32^2, 
$$
which is a parabola opening up, so it attains its minimum at its vertex, which occurs at
$$
t_\min
 = - \frac{-2\cdot 32 \cdot 16}{2\cdot \left(12^2+ 16^2\right)}
 = \frac{32}{9 + 16}
 = 1\frac{7}{25}
 = 1.28 \text{ hours}.
$$
You can now find the actual distance as $d(t_\min)$.

Comment: okay, my problem is with the premise - putting B moving along the positive x axis and A at (0,32) because this means the two ships never actually approach each other. They are always moving away? How does this make sense with the question?

Comment: Approaching only means that the distance between the ships is decreasing, not that it's $0$. So, once you find the equation for distance (squared) as shown in both answers, you want to find where it's minimized. "Ceasing to approach" means that the distance starts increasing from its minimum.

Comment: the specific wording of the question says the ships 'cease to approach one another'. this indicates that they are heading to the same point and then their paths diverge, hence why I conceptualized my diagram as a right angled triangle

Comment: How can they approach the same point when ship A is moving south while ship B is moving east? (Also, your setup with the right triangle was actually correct, but you needed to find the distance function and continue from there.)

Comment: Got it! (19.2 miles and 1.28 hours) Thank you

Comment: @mathwhiz73 yes, correct. See update to show how to do this without calculus.